# Page table entry size - why a power of 2?

Tags: cpu-architecture, page-tables

I solved some question, where the page table entry size needed only 26 bits - 22 for the physical address, and 4 for dirty bits and such. However it was rounded up to 32 - because 26 is not a power of 2. Must be something simple I'm missing but why do we have to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here that you need to realize that the page table entry needs to accessed like any other piece of data. Typically, this means that it needs to fit into a byte or a word.

Now bytes only hold 8 bits, so that is not enough room. For many machines (and I suspect, your machine too), words are 32 bits.

Thus the page table entry is allocated 32 bits of space.

Answer (score 0):

Number of entries in a page table entry and the size are two things. Obviously the size is equal to the number of entries times size of a single entry. Page table entry is there to tell you which virtual page maps to which physical page. Which means, the number of entries you need in a page table entry is, number of virtual page you have. which can be calculated by dividing the total addressable space by the size of a page. (For example, 32 bit address and a 4k page size gives us 2 to the power 20 entries), virtual part of an entry will be 20 bits. Size of a physical part entry is determined by the available physical memory. Usually the page size remain same. By this way you can calculate the bits needed for a single entry. Then you can multiply this by the number of entries and you have the total size.